# Unresponsive UI when launching a Task

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, javafx-2

I have a [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) that should return a list of `SomeObject` from a database:

```
public final class LoadTask extends Task<List<SomeObject>> {       

    @Override
    protected List<TodoTask> call() throws InterruptedException {
        List<SomeObject> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            list.addAll(servcie.getAllSomeObjects());
            // this task take a lot of time
        return list;
    }           
}
```

I use this task to fill a `TableView`:

```
@FXML
private void pullData() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    loadTask1 = new LoadTask();
    final Thread t = new Thread(loadTask1);
    t.start();
    todoList.getItems().addAll(loadTask1.get());
}
```

When I press the button that execute the `pullData()` the whole `UI` freeze until I get all the Objects from the database.

How can I fix the design to get a responsive `UI` ?

Comment: Wild guess: `loadTask1.get()`. What is `Task`?

Comment: @fge `Task` is [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html).

Comment: Which inherits `FutureTask`. And doesn't override `.get()`. Which means it will block until it gets the result ;)

Comment: Shouldn't it be "... while lunching *with* a thread"?("UI out for lunch with thread. Be back in a few minutes", SCNR... :-)

Comment: @fge Can you post a complete answer ?

Comment: Since I don't do JavaFX, that'll be hard :p

Comment: @Dirk Sorry, I can't get what you are trying to tell.

Comment: @tarrsalah - the typo in the question's headline ("lunching" instead of "launching"). Not so funny, actually, but it's one of these days...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I accomplish it.  Basically, I start a new task, and put a listener on that task for successful completion.  The costingService is an interface hibernate connection (via glassfish) to a MS SqlServer DB.  The listProducts method on that interface returns all of the products in the database.  loadTask contains the results of the database query when the task completes.  The pricingProductTableList is the ObservableList of the query results, and the pricingProductTable is the TableView that displays the data.  Here's the code:

```
    private ObservableList<Product> getProductList() {
    logger.info("Entering {}.getProductList", this.getClass().getName());
    if (costingService == null) {
        return null;
    }
    final Task<ObservableList> loadTask = new Task<ObservableList>() {
        @Override
        protected ObservableList call() throws Exception {
            return FXCollections.observableList(costingService.listProducts());
        }
    };

    loadTask.stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> source, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
            if (newState.equals(Worker.State.SUCCEEDED)) {
                if (pricingProductTableList != null && !pricingProductTableList.isEmpty()) {  // moved here from beginning of method, now table doesn't redraw
                    pricingProductTableList.clear();
                }
                pricingProductTableList = loadTask.getValue();
                pricingProductTable.getItems().setAll(pricingProductTableList);
                pricingProductTable.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(false);
                pricingProductTable.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(true);
                }
            } else if (newState.equals(Worker.State.FAILED)) {
                loadTask.getException().printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    new Thread(loadTask).start();

    return pricingProductTableList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your ListView as ListView of String and your Task as a Task of an ObservableList of String. Afterwards, you just can bind the items property of the listview to the task value property as follows:

```
listview.itemsProperty().bind(task.valueProperty());
```

Here is a bigger example:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    VBox vbox = new VBox(10.0);
    vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    final ListView<String> listview = new ListView<String>();

    final ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar(-1);
    bar.setVisible(false);

    final Button button = new Button("Fill");
    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {            
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            final Task<ObservableList<String>> task = new Task<ObservableList<String>>() {
                @Override
                protected ObservableList<String> call() throws Exception {
                    ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
                        items.add("Row#"+i);
                    }
                    return items;
                }                   
            };              
            bar.visibleProperty().bind(task.runningProperty());
            button.disableProperty().bind(task.runningProperty());
            listview.itemsProperty().bind(task.valueProperty());                
            Thread t = new Thread(task);
            t.start();
        }
    });     

    vbox.getChildren().addAll(listview, button, bar);
    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 300, 300);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Hope it helps.